# NSMenuItem Key Equivalent set to Enter key from Number Pad

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, keyboard-shortcuts, nsmenuitem

I want to set the Key Equivalent on an NSMenuItem to be the number pad's Enter key. I don't have a 10-key number pad on my desktop, but I was told that Function+Return on the main keyboard would emulate the Number Pad Enter key. However, when I try to do that in Interface Builder in the Key Equivalent field, my cursor just jumps to the next field.

How can I set, in Interface Builder, the number pad's Enter key to the Key Equivalent on an NSMenuItem?

If you'd like to provide the programmatic way to do it in the comments, that's fine and appreciated, but for full Answers to this question, please restrict them to doing it in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using Function+Return on my normal keyboard DID work to put the Keypad Enter key as the key equivalent. I went and got an extended physical keyboard that had a keypad. When I hit the Keypad Enter key in the Key Equivalent field, I got the same behavior I got when I hit the Function+Return. I tested it within the app and using Function+Return to set the key equivalent DID successfully bind that Menu Item to the Keypad Enter key... it's just that Xcode didn't SHOW that any key was really bound.